# Right way to get dependencies from private repository

Tags: git, go, bitbucket, go-modules, go-get

I have private `bitbucket` repo on `http://localhost:7990`  *clone link* `http://localhost:7990/scm/gom/bar.git`

`go.mod` looks like:

```
module mod.org/bar

go 1.13
```

References available in a remote repository:

```
git ls-remote  http://localhost:7990/scm/gom/bar.git 

From http://localhost:7990/scm/gom/bar.git
d456de4f12785b26ac27ba08cffb76687d1287c8        HEAD
d456de4f12785b26ac27ba08cffb76687d1287c8        refs/heads/master
f948bd47a22c5fb9abed5bff468a10fc24f67483        refs/tags/v1.0.0
```

I changed `.gitconfig` to

```
[url "http://localhost:7990/scm/gom"]
      insteadOf = https://mod.org
```

and tried to get module by `name`, get  `no such host` error:

```
go get -v mod.org/bar

go get lmod.org/bar: unrecognized import path "lmod.org/bar" (https fetch: Get https://lmod.org/bar?go-get=1: dial tcp: lookup lmod.org: no such host)
```

When I add extension `.git`

```
go get -v mod.org/bar.git 

go: finding lmod.org/bar.git v1.0.0
go: downloading lmod.org/bar.git v1.0.0
verifying lmod.org/bar.git@v1.0.0: lmod.org/bar.git@v1.0.0: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/lmod.org/bar.git@v1.0.0: 410 Gone
```

`go` download version with tag `v1.0.0` to `GOPATH = /Users/user/go"`:

```
$GOPATH
└── go
     └── pkg
         └── mod
             └── cache
                 └── download
                     └── mod.org
                         └── bar.git
                             └── @v
                                 ├── v1.0.0.info
                                 ├── v1.0.0.lock
                                 └── v1.0.0.zip.tmp882433775
```

, but I still can't use one as dependency in other go-project.

Comment: Why not use replace directives in your go.mod?

Comment: Why not simply put the code of the dependencies into $GOPATH/src?

Comment: @Markus W Mahlberg - I try to use local `bitbucket` repo as holder of self(private) dependencies. Also I use `go modules` to automation process of getting and versioning public/private dependencies.

Comment: @Volker -  I would like to work with private repo is public, but `replace` makes a noise into the configuration. To all my private dependencies I have to write `replace lmod.org/xxx => lmod.org/xxx.git v1.0.0`

Comment: Your local bitbucket has a hostname. So your import path would be `your.host.name/owner/repo`. And you can use the same path in your `$GOPATH`

Comment: @hbamithkumara -  should works  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61088072/8030651

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Steps* to solve the problem:

1️⃣ changed module declaration in `go.mod` to

```
module mod.org/gomod/bar

go 1.16
```

the same as `bitbucket` repositories structure

[image]

repo's references to cloning:

```
http://localhost:7990/scm/gomod/bar.git
ssh://git@mod.org/gomod/bar.git
```

2️⃣ change `.gitconfig`: add `insteadOf` (`ssh` or `https`)

```
# [url "http://localhost:7990/scm"]
[url "ssh://git@mod.org"]
      insteadOf = https://mod.org
```

3️⃣ add `https://mod.org` to private repository

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE="mod.org"
```

❗After all preparations the module will be accessible to `go mod download` from other  module by `version tags`

```
module mod.org/gomod/foo

go 1.16

require (
   mod.org/gomod/bar v1.0.0-beta.1
)

replace (
   mod.org/gomod/bar => mod.org/gomod/bar.git v1.0.0-beta.1
)
```

or manually

```
go get -u mod.org/gomod/bar.git
go get mod.org/gomod/bar.git@v1.0.0-beta.1
```

Answer (score 3):

The server for `https://mod.org/bar` needs to return `go-import` metadata following the protocol described in https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths.

Several open-source implementations exist, such as:

- [`rsc.io/go-import-redirector`](https://pkg.go.dev/rsc.io/go-import-redirector)
- [`github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/govanityurls`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/govanityurls)

You can store credentials (or access tokens) for both the HTTPS server and the underlying repository in a [`.netrc`](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-netrc) file, and use the [`GOPRIVATE`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Environment_variables) environment variable to tell the `go` command not to look for your private repo in the public proxy.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use private repo without `.git` extension because of go tools don't know the version control protocol of your private repo, git or svn or any other.

For `github.com` or `golang.org` they are hardcoded into go's source.

The go tool will do a `https` query to know that before fetching your private repo:

```
https://private/user/repo?go-get=1
```

If your private repo didn't support `https`, please use `replace` syntax of go module to tell go tools directly:

```
require private/user/repo v1.0.0

...

replace private/user/repo => private.server/user/repo.git v1.0.0
```

https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths